# Blow-up the two diagonals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'd like to blow-up the two diagonals $X=V(X_1-X_2)\cup V(X_1+X_2)$ (in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$) with center $\mathcal{O}=(0,0)$. I had the idea to use the blowup of the plane so that I obtain $\widetilde{X}\subseteq\mathbb{A}^2_k\times\mathbb{P}^1_k$ with equations

$$ \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l} X_1^2-X_2^2&=0 \\\ X_1T_2-X_2T_1&=0 \end{array}\right. $$

But I had the idea that the blowup of the diagonals should be two disjoints lines and here it seems not to be the case because the exceptionnal divisor is $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ but it should be two points.

I guess my error is to apply the blowup of the plane to my subvariety $X$ But how to do without that? I have the construction with 
$$ \text{Proj}(\oplus I^n ) $$
with $I=(X_1,X_2)$, but it give me the same thing because with $S=k[X_1,X_2]/(X_1^2-X_2^2)$ I get
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Proj}(\oplus I^n ) &= \text{Proj}(S[T_1,T_2]/(T_1X_2-X_1T_2)) \\\
 &= \text{Proj}(S\otimes_k k[T_1,T_2])/(T_1X_2-T_2X_1)
\end{align*}$$
so that $\widetilde{X}$ appears as the closed subscheme of $X\times_k \mathbb{P}^1_k$ given by equation $T_1X_2-T_2X_1=0$ and for $X_1=X_2=0$ I always has the same fiber and my two lines are not disjoints?

Comment: Are you trying to blow up the diagonals, or blow up the origin and observe that the strict transforms of the two lines are disjoint?

Comment: My problem comes from the example 1 [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/ggt05-hauser.pdf) where I guess that one blows-up the origin to observe that the two lines become disjoints

Comment: I think I find my mistake: $\oplus I^n=S[X_1T,X_2T]$ which is different with $S[T_1,T_2]/(T_1X_2-X_1T_2)$ (by $T_i\mapsto X_i T$) because there can be other relations

Comment: For example $X_1 T_1\mapsto X_1^2 T$ the same as $X_2 T_2$ because $X_1^2=X_2^2$ in $S$

Comment: In fact it seems to be the only relation when $I=(g_i)$ where the $g_i$ form a regular sequence...